# Sort four numbers without an array

Tags: java, sorting

I have an exercise where I need to put four numbers in ascending order and then descending **without using arrays**. I can only use loops and *if* statements. I've done it with three numbers, but now with four numbers I am unable to think of the logic.

```
  float great1 = 0, great2 = 0, great3 = 0, great4 = 0;
  int a = 7, b = 5, c = 6, d = 0;

  // Descending
  if (a > b && b > c) {
    great1 = a;
    great2 = b;
    great3 = c;

  } else if (a > b && b < c) {
    great1 = a;
    great2 = c;
    great3 = b;

  } else if (b > a && a > c) {
    great1 = b;
    great2 = a;
    great3 = c;

  } else if (b > a && a < c) {
    great1 = b;
    great2 = c;
    great3 = a;

  } else if (c > a && a > b) {
    great1 = c;
    great2 = a;
    great3 = b;
  }

  else {
    great1 = c;
    great2 = b;
    great3 = a;
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have with three numbers?

Comment: 3, or 4, or n numbers, the logic remains the same. Please show your effort.

Comment: Here is what I did until now

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A nice way to sort a small, fixed size of inputs is using a "**sorting network**".

This network sorts 4 elements, a b c d. Each line compares and swaps two elements:

```
int swap;
if (a > b) { swap = a; a = b; b = swap; }
if (c > d) { swap = c; c = d; d = swap; }
if (a > c) { swap = a; a = c; c = swap; }
if (b > d) { swap = b; b = d; d = swap; }
if (b > c) { swap = b; b = c; c = swap; }
```

If you want to sort in reverse order, just flip the `>` signs to `<` signs.

Links:

- [Sorting network - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network)
- ["Introduction to Sorting Networks" - Doug Hoyte](https://hoytech.github.io/sorting-networks/)
- [List of smallest and fastest sorting networks for a given number of inputs](https://bertdobbelaere.github.io/sorting_networks.html)

Comment: @user3500017 If this is a homework assignment, be prepared to explain this method to your instructor.

Answer (score -4):

I don’t know if this is correct or not. It might be better if it can be optimized.

```
// Sorted array
var t = [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38];
var expected = [38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31];
var s = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
  if(Math.round(t.length / 2) <= i) {
    var f = t[i];
    var g = t[t.length - i - 1];
    t[i] = g;
    t[t.length - i - 1] = f;
  }
}
if(JSON.stringify(t).replace(/ /g) == JSON.stringify(expected).replace(/ /g)) {
  console.log('true');
}
else {
  console.log('false');
}
```

This will swap value in between the center.

Comment: The question specifically says "without using arrays". Also, it asks for a Java solution, and JavaScript := Java.

Comment: @Dada: didn't you mean '!=' instead of ':=' ?