# MySQL custom function using arrays and sorting possible?

Tags: php, mysql, user-defined-functions

While it appears I'm unable to get any satisfactory answers concerning my last question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53803642/update-insert-delete-on-a-localhost-sqlite-db-file), I'm now looking to complete my project using MySQL instead of SQLite as my database background in a simple localhost environment.  The one thing I need to accomplish is using a user defined function (UDF) which PHP can handle nicely with SQLite using the following code in an UPDATE query:

```
function nPoints($n1, $n2, $n3, $n4)
{
    $numb = array($n1, $n2, $n3, $n4);
    sort($numb);
    return $numb[0] * 1 + $numb[1] * 2 + $numb[2] * 3 + $numb[3] * 4;
}
```

Essentially I am taking 4 numbers and doing a calculation which multiplies the smallest number by 1, then next smallest by 2, 3rd smallest by 3, and then the largest by 4 regardless if there are any ties or not.  can I do this likewise as a MySQL user-defined function, and if not then what's the cleanest way without doing things the trickier way such as quick sort logic using for-next loops and such?

If PHP can handle registering such user-defined functions like it can with SQLite that would be better actually but how?

Answer (score 1):

Why use sort()? Just write a quick sorting algorithm its only 4 numbers.
Alternatively you can do this in PHP (I assume you are connecting PHP to MYSQL).

No reason not to

`SELECT * FROM table;
//Perform Calculation
UPDATE table SET x = y WHERE something;`

Brute Force can be:

`$max = $N1 + $N2*2 + $N3*3 + N4*4;
IF ($max < $N1 + $N2*2 + $N4*3 + N3*4) THEN 
  $max = $N1 + $N2*2 + $N4*3 + N3*4
END IF
...
...
...
return $max;`

Comment: I would go for the PHP solution given by Eugene Lorman, it's easier to maintain on the long run.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost here.

1.  So in a MySQL function, I cannot use arrays and sort functions to simplify what I need to accomplish and resort to doing things the old way?

2.  Can I use PHP like I originally did to accomplish having a MySQL function as desired? If so then how?

Comment: I suppose as a last minute resort I could follow [this example] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070577/sort-4-numbers-without-array).